# How do I get a generic type to match if Class<Type> uses ? extends Type?

Tags: java, generics

Given this prototype:

```
public static <C extends SetComposite, S extends Iterable<U>, U> boolean
eligibleForInclusion(C me, Class<C> clazz, List<S> members) throws TypeCollisionException {
    ...
}
```

And this call site:

```
public void include(RestaurantSet member) {
    if (SetCompositeUtils.<RestaurantSetComposite, RestaurantSet, Restaurant>
            eligibleForInclusion(this, this.getClass(), Arrays.asList(member))) {
        inc.add(member);
    }
}
```

Eclipse compiler gives this error:

```
The parameterized method <RestaurantSetComposite, RestaurantSet, Restaurant>eligibleForInclusion(RestaurantSetComposite, Class<RestaurantSetComposite>, List<RestaurantSet>) of type SetCompositeUtils is not applicable for the arguments (RestaurantSetComposite, Class<capture#1-of ? extends RestaurantSetComposite>, List<RestaurantSet>)
```

If I'm reading correctly, `Class<capture#1-of ? extends RestaurantSetComposite>` is not matching `Class<RestaurantSetComposite>`. Can I get around this somehow?

Comment: Why are you explicitly specifying the type arguments when you call? What's the point of doing `this.getClass()` for the parameter of type `Class<C>` if you've already explicitly specified `C`?

Comment: I specify type arguments to enforce use of the right static method (I think not specifying these can lead to hard to find programming errors). The second part, providing Class<C>, is because I bucket based on class, and type erasure makes it impossible (as of java 1.7) to determine which subclass of C I'm dealing with at runtime.

Comment: what I'm trying to say is, the way you've explicitly specified it, isn't `RestaurantSetComposite.class` the only possible valid second argument? why not use that directly?

Comment: Indeed you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `this` might be an instance of a *subclass*, `this.getClass()` might not be exactly `RestaurantSetComposite.class`, so you need

```
public static <C extends SetComposite, S extends Iterable<U>, U> boolean
eligibleForInclusion(C me, Class<? extends C> clazz, List<S> members) throws TypeCollisionException {
    ...
}
```

Comment: That's definitely closer, but still won't compile: "The inferred type Test.RestaurantSet is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter `<S extends Iterable<U>>`"

Comment: @MattBall I can't reproduce.  But what is `RestaurantSet`?  If `RestaurantSet` implements `Iterable<Restaurant>` -- perhaps via `Set<Restaurant>` -- then there's no compilation error.  If it implements `Iterable<? extends Restaurant>` or `Iterable<RestaurantSubclass>`, then there is indeed the compilation error you quote.  Then you also need `S extends Iterable<? extends U>`.

Comment: RestaurantSet does indeed implement Iterable<Restaurant>.

Comment: This answer seems to fix the error, so +1. @ChrisBetti does using `Class<? extends C> clazz` instead still work for your solution?

Comment: Yes, this was exactly the issue. Great follow-on comment about needing to know the generic type parameters of anything RestaurantSet extends or implements, Jeremy, thank you.